# problem converting fortran file containing MODULE

Tags: fortran

I am converting a Fortran file using f2c. The file contains the definition of a MODULE, and I am unable to convert it. The error is Error on line 1 of machine.f: unclassifiable statement (starts "modulemach")

The file is pasted below:

```
MODULE MACHINE
IMPLICIT NONE
SAVE

! Machine dependant constants
integer, parameter :: kind_io4  = 4, kind_io8  = 8 , kind_ior = 8
&,                    kind_evod = 8, kind_dbl_prec = 8
&,                    kind_rad  = selected_real_kind(13,60) !the '60' maps to 64-bit real
&,                    kind_phys = selected_real_kind(13,60) ! the '60' maps to 64-bit real
&,                    kind_REAL = 8                         ! used in cmp_comm
&,                    kind_INTEGER = 4                      ! -,,-
real(kind=kind_evod), parameter :: mprec = 1.e-12 ! machine precision to restrict dep
END MODULE MACHINE
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Why are you translating what seems like good modern Fortran code?

Comment: Since it is Fortran >=90, there is another approach that might work.  If your goal is to make the code usable with a C or a C-compatible language, you can do that with the Fortran using the Fortran ISO C Binding.

Answer (score 5):

I've used f2c on a few occasions only, and don't have much experience with it, but isn't it a tool for converting **Fortran 77** code to **C**?

Modules are a Fortran feature that were introduced in Fortran 90, and they are not part of Fortran 77 (along with portable precision, e.g. KIND and some other stuff), and I don't know if C has an analog for those features. Somebody will surely clarify me on that.

Comment: Yes, exactly; f2c supports only F77. I suppose a rough analog to module variables would be file scope variables in C.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Actually, I have a large FORTRAN code that i wish to accelerate. The path i decided to take is that I will use f2c to convert FORTRAN to C an then I will port the compute intensive part to GPU using CUDA FORTRAN. NOw, I am facing this MODULE issue. Please suggest how to deal with FORTRAN 90 code. How to convert it to C. Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: @sohan - (and I'm quite sure others will back me up on this), but a translation like that could end up not being worth it. Modern Fortran code (like the one above) is already quite fast. Microoptimizations you will run into will probably end up getting you much smaller gain, than the problems you will have to deal with with translation (KIND for example, complete reorganization is another). C doesn't have a direct analogy to modules (that I'm aware of). And last, I'm sure this is a typo but in your first sentence "port it to C and then use CUDA FORTRAN for intensive part"??

Comment: http://www.pgroup.com/resources/cudafortran.htm // If anything I would  like @M. S. B. suggested port only the parts that intercooperate with C, leaving the intensive stuff in Fortran's domain.

Comment: yes.. it was a typo.. I mean i want to convert Fortran to C using f2c and then i want to port the compute intensive subroutines to GPU using C for CUDA not CUDA FORTRAN.

Comment: @sohan - Well, ... the rest of my answer stands. You cannot (AFAIK) translate it without losing some features. My recommendation goes with what M.S.B. said in the comment - use ISO C bindings to interconnect Fortran with C.